# Parametrizing 3D geometry for shape optimization

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to parametrize a 3D geometry for shape optimization. The structure looks like the following. Another real example is [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Fa0SllpGhMg/TJoIB9knilI/AAAAAAAAApY/35FGPCrmLdo/s1600/Little+Rudder.jpg).

[image]

Currently I am using `BSplines` to create the lower part and using symmetry to create the whole down part of the foil. Here is what I get.
[image]
[image]

Now I have many control points to take care in order to run a shape optimization. I also don't know how to join the upper part with the bottom hydrofoil part in a sensible way. I don't know how to design a good  middle part of the foil (fat nose part of the foil) where the upper part is linked to. I also need to accompany a [flap](http://fun3d.larc.nasa.gov/flap.png) with in the geometry.

Please offer some suggestion for parametrization of such a surface so that we can manipulate the geometry from MMA. The less control points are there better the situation is for optimization. May be combination of some analytic function in 3D. But I doubt if that is possible.

BR

Comment: That is a lot of questions. What exactly do you mean by "I am trying to parametrize a 3D geometry for shape optimization." Well if it, say, the hight then write a function which has as argument the hight and return the 3D object. Where is the problem?

Comment: @ruebenko I did exactly such a function implementation to create the second picture. But I am still way behind from creating a real geometry like the first pic that can be manipulated with certain set of parameters.The second geometry is natively created in MMA where as the first pic comes from a stl CAD import.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two choices: 1) create the second part of the geometry and then write a face-face intersection algorithm to merge them. 2) create the second part of the geometry and write two functions that return -1 if a query point is inside the geometry and +1 if it is out side (other values will do). Then use `RegionPlot3D[ f1[x,y,z]<0 || f2[x,y,z]<0,....]`. The idea is the to extract the `GraphicsComplex` and use that. The question is going to be how well you can approximate the corners with that. Here is an illustration of what I mean.

```
if1[x_, y_, z_] := If[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, -1, 1]
if2[x_, y_, z_] := If[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 <= 1 && -1.5 <= z <= 1.5, -1, 1]

res = RegionPlot3D[
  if1[x, y, z] < 0 || if2[x, y, z] < 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
   2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

Then extract the coords and the polygons.

```
coords = res[[1, 1]];
poly = Cases[res[[1]], _Polygon, Infinity];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords, poly], Boxed -> False]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying with the first technique. Anyways your answer gives a good insight. By the way few days back on a question on Quadmesh you wanted to know how I use GMSH for quad meshing. I updated this question with picture of the foil with such mesh.

Comment: OK, the majority of those patches are actually triangles with their Voronoi meshes drawn into it.

Comment: The mesh is nowhere near to optimal because the geometry definition I wrote in MMA were bad as an input to GMSH.